# Flutter: Moving from one dialog to another

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I move from one dialog to another and close the previous one?

I made two dialogs and when I move to the next one the previous one does not close. I want the previous one, `WelcomeDialog` to close when I click continue and the next dialog open.

```
class WelcomeDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 220,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50, 20, 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Welcome!',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Thank you for joining! Let\'s get you started.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return const CommonDialog();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Continue',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                        side: const BorderSide(
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CommonDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommonDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text(
        'Update Information',
      ),
      content: const Text('We need to update your information,'),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('Continue'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply do a `Navigator.pop(context)` before you show the next one?

Comment: @IvoBeckers I tried adding `Navigator.pop(context)`  in the `onPressed`, but the button stops working.

Comment: did you do it before  the `showDialog`? because that's necessary, because if you do it after you are popping the new one, making it look like nothing happens

Comment: @IvoBeckers That is exactly what I was doing.  ***smh***
Thank you so much!